# Collection with equal elements in .Net configuration section

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, collections

I am interested, if it is possible to have collection with same elements in .Net configuration.
Like this, for example:

```
                <RetrySettings>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="0:05:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="0:10:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="0:30:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="1:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="4:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="8:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="8:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="8:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="8:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="8:00:00"/>
                <RetryTurn PeriodBeforeRetry="8:00:00"/>
            </RetrySettings>
```

without adding annoying `id="someUniqueId"` attributes to each `RetryTurn` member?

I don't see how to make this, using custom collection, derived from `ConfigurationElementCollection`... Any possible solution for this?

Comment: Why would you want to have identical configuration values? The config files are for key/value configuration pairs. Those have no key.

Comment: I want just a collection with a possibility to iterate thru.
Also, it is specified like this in my tech.spec. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the workaround. 
In `RetryTurn` class define internal `Guid` property `UniqueId` and initialize it with new `Guid` value in default constructor:

```
public class RetryTurnElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public RetryTurnElement()
    {
        UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    internal Guid UniqueId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

In `RetryTurnCollection` class override `GetElementKey` method like this:

```
    public class RetryTurnCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((RetryTurnElement)element).UniqueId;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine you could also use `static int nextId = 0;` with a `lock` object for safety, then in the constructor set `UnqiueId = nextId++;`  So then your Ids would be ordered int's instead of Guids of a random order.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
public class RetryTurnCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return element;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the `PeriodBeforeRetry` attribute as your unique identifier? [`GetElementKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.getelementkey.aspx) returns an `object`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: `PeriodBeforeRetry` can't be used as unique identifier because it's value is not required to be unique, i.e. several `RetryTurn` elements with same values of `PeriodBeforeRetry` can exist in one collection.